# Babylon.js custom scene doesn't load

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I used this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/06/28/babylon-js-how-to-load-a-babylon-file-produced-with-blender.aspx to load a Babylon file.

```
if (BABYLON.Engine.isSupported()) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

    BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "scene.babylon", engine, function (newScene) {
        newScene.executeWhenReady(function () {
            // Attach camera to canvas inputs
            newScene.activeCamera.attachControl(canvas);

            // Once the scene is loaded, just register a render loop to render it
            engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
                newScene.render();
            });
        });
    }, function (progress) {
        // To do: give progress feedback to user
    });
}
```

Initially it wasn't working, but then I defined the mimeMap in the web config file, it started working

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".babylon" mimeType="application/babylon" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".babylonmeshdata" mimeType="application/babylonmeshdata" />
```

The problem is when I change scene.babylon to my head.babylon, it doesn't work. Nothing loads on Firefox and I get this error on IE:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

I did try head.babylon on http://www.babylonjs.com/sandbox/ and it loads just fine. Any suggestions on what I can do next?

Comment: Sounds like a missing property (thou it doesn't really explains why it works in the sandbox). Could you somehow show the scene you are trying to load? maybe without the large arrays in the meshes (assuming they are there, of course) ?

Comment: Hi Raanan, I finally figured it out. I had an older Babylon.js version, once I got the latest it just worked. Thank you for reaching out!

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Bablylon.js file to the latest and it just worked. I should have tried that sooner. Thanks everybody!